# Unirest Api Post call (error - not indexable)

Tags: c#, curl, unirest

I have a curl request to an api thus:

`curl xx.yy.zz:8080 -X POST --data "bb=True&alg=egbis&image_url=https://someurl.com/someimage.jpg"`

and this returns valid json results back.

Now trying to call this from a C# application using `Unirest`thus:

```
        string postData = "\"bb=True&alg=egbis&image_url=" + url + "\"";
        HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://xx.yy:8080/")
                .body(postData)
                .asJson<string>();
```

Have also tried without a double-quote preceding the bb=true and including/excluding the `--data` param in post string.

But keep getting this error:
`"{\"error\":\"not indexable\"}\r\n"`

Have been stuck on this for the last couple of hours, pretty sure it's something silly, but am at a loss.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out should pass the params as values

```
        HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://xx.yy")
            .field("bb","true")
            .field("alg","egbis")
            .field("image_url",url)
                .asJson<string>();
```